# oauth2.0 利用時の認可コードはサーバー間で共有しても良い？

Tags: security, oauth

OAuth２.0において、認可サーバーから発行された認可コードをサーバー間で共有し、認可サーバーからの発行先と異なるサーバーからリソースへアクセスすることは仕様上許容される操作なのでしょうか。

推奨されないであろうということはわかるのですが、RFC6749などを確認する限り、サードパーティーアプリケーションは単一のサーバーであるということが定義されていないため、仕様上は問題ないのではないかと考えています。
https://openid-foundation-japan.github.io/rfc6749.ja.html#client-types
もし、こちらについてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。

*実装イメージ

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3):

認可コードは1回使うと無効化されるので共有することはできません。
[4.1.2.  認可レスポンス](https://openid-foundation-japan.github.io/rfc6749.ja.html#code-authz-resp)

> もし認可コードが2回以上使用された場合は, 認可サーバーはリクエストを拒否しなければならず (MUST)

[アクセストークン](https://openid-foundation-japan.github.io/rfc6749.ja.html#anchor8)を共有したい、という話であれば可能でしょう。
ただし[クライアント認証](https://openid-foundation-japan.github.io/rfc6749.ja.html#client-authentication)において図中のサーバー1,2がともに同一クライアントであるとみなされる必要があります。

(サーバー1, 2 が各々独自にリソースサーバーへアクセスするのではなく、Gatewayサーバー的なものを経由するようにしてアクセスを1本化するのが一般的かと思います。)

Comment: ちなみに「認証コード」という用語はOAuth2.0仕様上にはありません。(図に登場する「認可コード」だとみなして回答しています)